# What is the best way to add more than one row of copied content to new rows in separate sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to create a spreadsheet "hub" for personal organization/tracking/productivity. I currently have an "input" page where I record start times, end times, activity name, and activity notes.

The organization of that isn't the problem. I want the content to copy itself to my "inputCollect" sheet and then clear the content. This will happen when the date I have in A2 is not the current date. (Essentially creating a clear slate each day).

I've spent quite a few hours looking through resources and have run into a few workarounds I could do, but **I'd like to figure out what would be the most efficient process**.

Please judge as much as you wish, I have only one semester of experience so I'm aware much of what I'm doing may be extra work, too complicated, or I may be forgetting simple things. *I'm burnt out)*.

**Here is an example of the Table:**

| Date | Start | End | Name | Note | Return |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/16 | 2:00PM |  | Med1 | 5mg | =IFNA(output!E2,"") |
|  | 2:10PM | 2:13 PM | Eat | Meal | =IFNA(output!E3,"") |

*(Return is where I host formulas for if the Name and Note have medicine data where I calculate when the effect will wear off. Copy/paste may mess it up but I can figure that out myself.)*

These are my notes. Each untested.

**Base Info**

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inputSS= ss.getSheetByName("input");
  var inputCollectSS= ss.getSheetByName("inputCollect");

function onOpen(){
  var cellDate=inputSS.getRange('A2');
  var valueCellDay=cellDate.getValue();
  var dateToday=new Date();
  ss.setActiveSheet(inputSS);
```

**Using Values**

```
//variation one partial
  if (dateToday.getDay() != valueCellDay.getDay()){
    //i'll want the new sheet to have date, but i can do that later
    var valuesToMove = inputSS.getSheetValues(2, 2, -1, 6);
    Logger.log(valuesToMove);
    //this is when I want to appendrow(), but the values aren't single rows
    //i'd continue but brain died
  };
}
```

**Using Ranges/Number of Rows**

```
//variation two
  if (dateToday.getDay() != valueCellDay.getDay()){
    var rangeInput=inputSS.getRange(2, 2, -1, 5);
    var rangeRowsN=rangeInput.getNumRows();
    inputCollectSS.insertRowsBefore(2, rangeRowsN);
    rangeInput.copyTo(inputCollectSS.getRange(2,2,rangeRowsN,5));
    //this clears Date to Note columns (note 5 not 6)
    //this is to keep the formula from the return column there.
    inputSS.getRange(2,1,rangeRowsN,5).clearContent();
    //to set date for next trigger to use
    inputSS.getRange("A2").setValue(dateToday);   
  }
```

**ON EDIT**

I've tested the second variation a bit and this is what I've adjusted it to at the moment: (Warning. Still messy.)

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function onOpen(){
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inputSS= ss.getSheetByName("input");
  var inputCollectSS= ss.getSheetByName("inputCollect");
  var cellDate=inputSS.getRange('A2');
  var valueCellDay=cellDate.getValue();
  var dateToday=new Date();
  ss.setActiveSheet(inputSS);
  var rowNumber= inputSS.getLastRow();
  if (dateToday.getDay() !== valueCellDay.getDay()){
    Logger.log(rowNumber);
    var rangeInput=inputSS.getRange(2, 2, (rowNumber+1), 5);
    inputCollectSS.insertRowsBefore(2, (rowNumber+1));
    rangeInput.copyTo(inputCollectSS.getRange(2,2,(rowNumber+1),5));
    inputSS.getRange(2,1,rangeRowsN,5).clearContent();
    inputSS.getRange("A2").setValue(dateToday);   
  }
}
```

**end edit**
The resources I have bookmarked for possible use are `InsertRowsAfter()/InsertRowsBefore()` `clearContent()` `copyTo()` `getValues()/getSheetValues()` `getNumRows` `getDataRange` `moveTo()` `appendRow()` `getRange()`

I'm sure this is messy, but I hope it gets the point across for what I want to do.

This is a new spreadsheet so I'm flexible in format (as you can see by the `appendrow()` vs `insertRowsBefore()`).

Thanks!

Comment: Use `setVallues()`  dealing with  data in arrays is much faster.  Adding rows like this `sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,array.length,array[0].length).setValues(array);`  If you use multiple functions consecutively where your rereading that data you may want to add SpreadsheetApp.flush() at the end of some functions to insure that the data is available to be read by the next function.

Comment: @Cooper thank you!! I'll play around with this.

Comment: You can use a timebased trigger to transfer the data array and clear your daily log at a regular time.  Some users have found that they are unreliable but my experience is that they are highly reliable. You can create new triggers programmatically from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String))

Comment: Spend time reading the documentation until you understand it.  If you really want to learn a lot about google apps script volunteer here.  Many of the volunteers here are very knowledgeable.